# Cisco 2100. При включении mac filtering, компьютер не подключается к сети. Что делать?

Tags: wifi, cisco

Настроенный и долгие годы работавший без нареканий контроллер Wi-Fi Cisco 2100 перестал обрабатывать Mac Filtering - при указанных ниже настройках устройства не подключаются к Wi-Fi сети, хотя и видят её. (windows не удалось подключится к сети, с телефонов тоже не соединяется)

Layer 2 - security none, включен только Mac Filtering. Адреса вбииты на странице Security, Mac Filtering. Вбиты правильно, до этого всё работало.
Layer 3 - security none, если отключена Web Policy - устройства не подключаются, если включена - не отрабатывает Mac Filtering и девайс падает на страницу авторизации.

Если выключить вообще  все настройки безопасности - сеть работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема?.

[image: General]
[image: Layer2]

---

Проблема самоустранилась. Видимо был затык где-то ещё.